# nodejs - how to remove part of a string after a delimiter

Tags: javascript, node.js, webtorrent, inquirerjs

I'm using this code in a nodejs script to push some elements inside an array for `list` question type of inquirerjs.

```js
for (let [index, torrent] of results.entries()) {
    if (torrent.seeds > 0 && torrent.peers > 0) {
        filesList.push(`${torrent.title} s:${torrent.seeds} p:${torrent.peers}`);
        filesDetails.push(torrent);
    } else {
        results.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm adding the `s:value` and the `p:value` after the filename to inform the user about seeds and peers of a file. When the user select a file from the list, I'm searching into the array of objects to find the file and serve it back. If I don't add the `s:value` and the `p:value` to the file name, all is working as expected but since I need to provide this informations, how I can remove them from the file name before looping the array?

This is the code I'm using at the moment to find the right file into the objects array

```js
const selectedTorrent = [];
for (let f of filesDetails) {
    if (f.title === availableTorrents.selected) {
        selectedTorrent.push(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not do `filesList.push({title: torrent.title, s: torrent.seeds, p: torrent.peers}`? seems like an anti-pattern to use a string if you need individual values later on somewhere else

Comment: @LawrenceCherone because I'm using `fileList` for inquirerjs question choices. I don't know if it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear how "filesList" is used in the second snippet, but to answer the question in the title, you can remove the part starting from "s:" using a combination of the string built-in functions `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
let title = `Torrent title s:${torrent.seeds} p:${torrent.peers}`;

let strippedTitle = title.substring(0, title.indexOf(" s:")); // returns "Torrent title"
```

indexOf: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

substring: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: `filesList` is provided to inquirerjs to provide the choices for the user. When the user select a possible choice, it's added to the `availableTorrents.selected` that is used in the second snippet for file name comparision! Your solution will remove also the `p:` ?

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Yes, this solution will remove the "p:" too. It takes a substring from character at index 0 (the beginning) to the index of the string " s:". I'll update the answer with some docs on the methods

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! :)